# How effective is FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection

I am using FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS in my php code to sanitize the inputs.

Do i really need to user mysql_escape_string? Can i prevent sql injection and other attacks from filter functions only?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want to use standard techniques to sanitize input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS` and `mysql_escape_string`. Use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). With prepared statements you don't need to escape inputs manually.

Comment: Oh..Okay,but for now will the filter function solve the purpose because a lot of code is wriiten without PDO.

Comment: For that case use mysql_real_escape_string. But you need to be very careful with this. Here is some material about SQL injection: http://webappsec.org/projects/articles/091007.txt .

Comment: Is there any disadvantage of using the filter?

Comment: Yes. It does not escape characters needed to be escaped to avoid sql injection.

Comment: Just one last query.Thanks for you time and efforts. If i do print an apostrophe using filter sanitize special chars , it prints out &#39 in the browser source . So does that also mean it can  sanitize it and won't create any problem if escape string is not used. It does not print an apostrophe right away but prints &#39;

Comment: It may do the work... But I would recommend you to use mysql_real_escape_string as it is created specially for that purpose. And if you want to sanitize html input, use htmlspecialchars.